# Dot Product Force

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics, momentum

Konopinski's "What the electromagnetic vector potential describes" (Gaussian dimension) equation (3):
$$\frac{d}{dt}[M\vec{v}+(q/c)\vec{A}]=-\nabla q[\phi-(\vec{v}/c)\cdot\vec{A}].\tag{3}$$

contains a dot product between two vector quantities:

The electron velocity and the vector potential.

Back in the days of analog computers, a "four quadrant multiply" (multiply in quadrature aka multiply of two signed numbers) was no simple matter to build because, at least in circuit theory, there is no simple electronic component that does the job. One might conceive of such an analog multiply based on the right hand side of (3). Are there other physical laws that might similarly be exploited to do an analog multiply between two signed numbers?

Comment: ...I don't understand the question. Yes, when you have the term $\vec v \cdot \vec A$, then larger $\vec A$ will make this quantity larger even if $\vec v$ is small. What's the question about that?

Comment: I added a paragraph to explicate what I see as strange in this physical system.

Comment: Equation (3) is just Newton's 2nd law with the Lorentz force.

Comment: Since v8 I still don't understand what the question is asking - your last sentence doesn't make sense. It sounds like it's asking whether there are any other physical vectors that can be involved in a dot product.

Comment: I'll put it like this:  Back in the days of analog computers, a "four quadrant multiply" (multiply in quadrature aka multiply of two signed numbers) was no simple matter to build because, at least in circuit theory, there is no simple electronic component that does the job. One might conceive of such an analog multiply based on the right hand side of (3).  Are there other physical laws that might similarly be exploited to do an analog multiply between two signed numbers?

Answer (score 3):

> It will increase an electron's momentum in the electron's current
>   direction

One must also take the gradient of that dot product so your conclusion isn't valid.

Assume, for simplicity, that

$$\phi = 0$$

$$\vec A = A_x(x,y,z)\; \hat{\mathbf x}$$

The first equation is then

$$M\vec a + \frac{q}{c}\left(\nabla A_x \cdot \vec v \right)\hat{\mathbf x} = \frac{q}{c}\nabla\left(A_x v_x\right) = \frac{q}{c}v_x\left(\nabla A_x \right)$$

Now, let the velocity at time $t = 0$ be

$$\vec v(0) = v_0 \hat{\mathbf x}$$

so that, at that instant, the velocity and vector potential are co-linear.  Then

$$M\vec a(0) + \frac{q}{c}\left(\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial x} v_0 \right)\hat{\mathbf x} = \frac{q}{c}v_0\left(\nabla A_x \right) $$

which simplifies to

$$M \vec a(0) = \frac{q}{c}v_0\left(\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial y}\hat{\mathbf y} +  \frac{\partial A_x}{\partial z}\hat{\mathbf z}\right)$$

As expected, the rate of change of momentum in the current direction is zero, i.e., the magnetic force is orthogonal to the charged particle's velocity.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the error in my question.  I had taken someone's word for the interpretation of the equation regarding momentum without examining it in detail and you caught it.  

I would really like to give you credit for answering this question but the essence of my erroneously stated question is not actually dependent on the error. Is there any way I can award you credit for catching the error, try to reword my question without the error you caught and then, if you answer it, provide you additional credit for answering it?

Comment: Did you mean:


$v_0 = \vec v(0) \hat{\mathbf x} $


?

Comment: James, $\vec v(0) = v_0\hat{\mathbf x}$ implies that $v_0 = \vec v(0) \cdot \hat{\mathbf x}$ if that's what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like your translation of Konoponski's equation (which you reference as "The first equation") is correct if the position of the charge is, for example, at the maximum poynting vector of a Hertz dipole, but is incorrect if the electron is in its null (ie:  There is no curl in A.)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna#Hertzian_dipole

Comment: I've simplified the question to avoid errors and get to the point.